# Stripping variable borders with python re

Tags: python, regex

How does one replace a pattern when the substitution itself is a variable?

I have the following string:

```
s = '''[[merit|merited]] and [[eat|eaten]] and [[go]]'''
```

I would like to retain only the right-most word in the brackets ('merited', 'eaten', 'go'), stripping away what surrounds these words, thus producing:

`merited and eaten and go`

I have the regex:

`p = '''\[\[[a-zA-Z]*\[|]*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]'''`

...which produces:

```
>>> re.findall(p, s)
['merited', 'eaten', 'go']
```

However, as this varies, I don't see a way to use re.sub() or s.replace().

Comment: I don't understand the question? It looks like the regex is already doing what you want it to do?  Unless maybe you want `re.findall(p,s)[-1]`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Edited the question.

Comment: Just loop through the list of your words , and keep calling re.findall

Comment: Still a bit unclear. Can you show your inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = '''[[merit|merited]] and [[eat|eaten]] and [[go]]'''
p = '''\[\[[a-zA-Z]*?[|]*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]'''
re.sub(p, r'\1', s)
```

`?` so that for `[[go]]` first `[a-zA-Z]*` will match empty (shortest) string and second will get actual `go` string

`\1` substitutes first (in this case the only) match group in a pattern for each non-overlapping match in the string `s`. `r'\1'` is used so that `\1` is not interpreted as the character with code 0x1

Answer (score 4):

well first you need to fix your regex to capture the whole group:

```
>>> s = '[[merit|merited]] and [[eat|eaten]] and [[go]]'
>>> p = '(\[\[(?:[a-zA-Z]*\|)*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\])'
>>> [('[[merit|merited]]', 'merited'), ('[[eat|eaten]]', 'eaten'), ('[[go]]', 'go')]
[('[[merit|merited]]', 'merited'), ('[[eat|eaten]]', 'eaten'), ('[[go]]', 'go')]
```

This matches the whole `[[whateverisinhere]]` and separates the whole match as group 1 and just the final word as group 2. You can than use `\2` token to replace the whole match with just group 2:

```
>>> re.sub(p,r'\2',s)
'merited and eaten and go'
```

or change your pattern to:

```
p = '\[\[(?:[a-zA-Z]*\|)*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]'
```

which gets rid of grouping the entire match as group 1 and only groups what you want. you can then do:

```
>>> re.sub(p,r'\1',s)
```

to have the same effect.

POST EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I actually changed your regex so here is the explanation:

```
\[\[(?:[a-zA-Z]*\|)*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]
\[\[                           \]\] #literal matches of brackets
    (?:           )* #non-capturing group that can match 0 or more of whats inside
       [a-zA-Z]*\| #matches any word that is followed by a '|' character
                    ( ...    ) #captures into group one the final word
```

I feel like this is stronger than what you originally had because it will also change if there are more than 2 options:

```
>>> s = '[[merit|merited]] and [[ate|eat|eaten]] and [[go]]'
>>> p = '\[\[(?:[a-zA-Z]*\|)*([a-zA-Z]*)\]\]'
>>> re.sub(p,r'\1',s)
'merited and eaten and go'
```

Comment: I suspect `'\[\[(?:[a-zA-Z]+\|)*([a-zA-Z]+)\]\]'` would be better for the regex unless the words can actually be zero letters long?

Comment: good point but it does no harm to be safe to match for emptiness. Matching what OP had, there may be zero-length words but one can never be sure